# Create asp:Repeater with links from list of files in folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I have an application that creates PDFs and stores them on a file within the website.  I need to loop through each of those files and find documents with a specific name on it.  I'm able to create that list without any issues, but getting stumped with the best method to create my links

This is what I have so far:

```
string rootFolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Forms/Offers");
string listOfBidSheets = @"*" + prospect.LastName.Trim() + "_" + prospect.FirstName.Trim() + "*";
string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath, listOfBidSheets);

if (fileList.Length > 0)
{  
    rptPDFLinks.DataSource = fileList;
    rptPDFLinks.DataBind();
}
```

The part that is stumping me is what to put on the front-end of the code:

```
<li><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item") %></li>
```

Normally when I bind to a repeater the Container.DataItems are easy because they are column names.

Any thoughts on where to take this?  I'm open to different solutions all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataBinder class is a fine way to render a property of the DataItem with some optional formatting. In your case the DataItem is just a string so you don't want to use the DataBinder. You can directly use the DataItem as such:

```
<li><%# Container.DataItem %></li>
```

This code won't give you a link though. You want to do something like this:

```
<li><a href="/Forms/Offers/<%# Container.DataItem %>"><%# Container.DataItem %></a></li>
```

You also need to strip out the path from the file names. Here's an example using some LINQ (you need to add 'using System.Linq' at the top of your file:

```
rptPDFLinks.DataSource = fileList.Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x));
rptPDFLinks.DataBind();
```

Comment: the fileList gives me a full path like: http://localhost:45658/Forms/Offers/C:/Users/jonharding/Dropbox/Projects/Coyle/HomeBuyers/Coyle/Coyle/Forms/Offers/Harding_Jon_09_27_2012.pdf. Is there a way to strip out just the filename and the extension?  removing all of the paths before it?

Comment: yup. you can use System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath).  i'll edit my answer to provide a demo.

Comment: I'm getting this error:
'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I just added using System.Linq; to the top and it worked.  Thanks for the help!